# Grouped JqGrid with summary export

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i would like to export my jqgrid to excel. and this code is working fine for basic jqgrid but i want to export grouping jqgrid with summary with each group. i am not able to export all data. summary of each group not exported. and i am not able to get the summary of each group in javascript to send manually to server.

I am Use Jqgrid client side only for server side i am just generating the excel all data posted back to server for excel generation using form submit.

This is my Grid  :
Read Border data not export in excel.

[image]

And this my Excel file

[image]

and My Export function in javascript is :

```
function fun(){alert("call"); 

//options = ['xmlstring','grid'];
//jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('jqGridExport',options);
//userdata = jQuery("#list2").getUserData;

 numberOfRecords = $("#list2").getGridParam("records");

var mya=new Array();
    total = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('footerData','get'); // to get the last footer data
    obj2 = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getCol','amount','array','sum');
    group = jqobj.groupField;

mya=jQuery("#list2").getDataIDs();  // Get All IDs
var data=jQuery("#list2").getRowData(mya[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
var colNames=new Array();  
var ii=0;
var html="";
for (var i in data){colNames[ii++]=i;
html = html +i+"\t";}    // capture col names
html = html + "\n";
for(i=0;i<mya.length;i++)
    {
        data=jQuery("#list2").getRowData(mya[i]); // get each row
        for(j=0;j<colNames.length;j++)
            {
                html=html+data[colNames[j]]+"\t"; // output each column as tab delimited
            }
        html=html+"\n";  // output each row with end of line

    }

for(j=0;j<colNames.length;j++)
{
    html=html+total[colNames[j]]+"\t"; // output each column as tab delimited
}   

html=html+"\n";  // end of line at the end
//document.forms[0].csvBuffer.value = csv
alert(html);
document.forms[0].csvBuffer.value=html;
document.forms[0].method='POST';
document.forms[0].action='csvExport.jsp';  // send it to server which will open this contents in excel file
document.forms[0].target='_blank';
document.forms[0].submit();

}
```